# Помогите! Необходимо найти ошибку или несколько в отрывке. Написать отредактированный вариант

Tags: орфография

**Изучив политическую ситуацию, был сделан вывод о том, что СЩА проиграли на Украине, но пока не готовы это признать.**

Список возможных ошибок: нарушение правил употребления паронимов, омонимов, синонимов, связанное с неточным знанием значений слова, плеоназм и тавтология, многозначность слова, использование фразеологических средств, перевод прямой речи в косвенную, употребление полных и кратких  форм прилагательного, конструкции с деепричастным оборотом, употребление местоимения "свой", личные местоимения и контекст, ошибки в сочетаниях однородных членов,согласование определений,нарушение синтаксической сочетаемости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Редактирование:**

*Изучив политическую ситуацию, можно **сделать** вывод, что США проиграли на Украине, но пока не готовы это признать.*

**Ошибки и неточности:**

1. Неправильное построение **деепричастного** оборота.

[§212. Деепричастные обороты](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)

Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится, как правило, к **подлежащему** данного предложения. В **безличном** предложении (нет подлежащего) можно использовать деепричастный оборот, но при этом в сказуемом должен быть **инфинитив.**

2. Указательное слово ***о том*** не является обязательным. Можно считать плеоназмом, лишней информацией.

**[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4)**

**Пример** без указательного слова: *Учитывая всё это, хочется сразу сделать **вывод, что** задача неразрешима.*

**Примечание**

**Стиль информативный**: необходимая информация при **наименьшем** объеме текста. Также: **Отглагольные** существительные рекомендуется заменять **глаголами**.  Обоснованное употребление союзов и **местоимений.**

Comment: Sharon, скажите, пожалуйста, о каких отглагольных существительных и местоимениях идёт речь? Или это доп. информация?

Comment: Я сравниваю свой ответ и ответ Галины. Она использует сущ.  при изучении, а не глагол изучить.  А местоимение – это лишнее указательное слово, тоже должна быть экономия. В некоторых издательствах очень серьезно относятся к информативности стиля, все считают.  Но это касается в первую очередь нехудожественных текстов.  Предполагается,  что прочтение  такой литературы должно быть быстрым, оценочным, а то читать не будут.  А это деньги, вещь серьезная)

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

*По изучении политической ситуации был сделан вывод о том, что США проиграли на Украине, но пока не готовы это признать.*

*Анализ политической ситуации позволил сделать вывод о том, что США проиграли на Украине, но пока не готовы это признать.*

(Кем сделан вывод, сознательно скрывается?)

Comment: намеренно сделана ошибка в аббревиатуре СЩА, какие виды ошибок из списка указать?

Comment: Кем сделан вывод нет информации

Comment: Тогда "красивее" второй предложенный мной вариант, с анализом. См. также https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC&mode=spravka Никакого плеоназма. Я редактор, если что. )))